How to create a standalone embeddable script from an internal Vue component?
I have a Vue application, and within, I have a component, which I reuse throughout the app. It's located in src/components.
I'd now like to make it so this component can be embedded into other applications/websites too, using a script. What's the best way to achieve this? Do I extract it into a separate Vue project and build and embed it? Is there a better approach?

Create a separate sub-app with this component alone. Or build it to a web component.
